# "Items must be empty before using Items Source" when updating MapItemsControl.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, xaml, dictionary, windows-phone-8

I have a Map control with MapsItemControl in it:

```
<maps:Map x:Name="MyMap">
    <maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
        <maptk:MapItemsControl>
            <maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    . . .
                </DataTemplate>
            </maptk:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </maptk:MapItemsControl>
    </maptk:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```

I populate the `MapItemsControl` in the code the following way:

```
var itemCollection = MapExtensions.GetChildren((Map)MyMap).OfType<MapItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
itemCollection.ItemsSource = myItemCollection;
```

This works correctly when adding items to the map for the first time. But if I want to update it with a new soruce item collection, I get the following error in `itemCollection.ItemsSource = myItemCollection;` line:

> Items must be empty before using Items Source

So, I have tried by adding a line to my code, in order to remove items before setting the source again, with no success:

```
var itemCollection = MapExtensions.GetChildren((Map)MyMap).OfType<MapItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
itemCollection.Items.Clear();
itemCollection.ItemsSource = myItemCollection;
```

Now I get the folowing exception in line `itemCollection.Items.Clear();`:

> Collection is in non writeable mode

How can I update the items in the `MapItemsControl`?

Comment: Are you adding items manually at some point? By using `itemCollection.Add(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Items gets locked if you bind it with ItemsSource... but if you add each item with Item.Add(item), it works fine.
So what I ended up doing was this:

```
var itemCollection = MapExtensions.GetChildren((Map)MyMap)
                                  .OfType<MapItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
if(itemCollection != null && itemCollection.Items.Count >0)
{
    itemCollection.Items.Clear();
}
foreach(var item in YourPushpinCollection)
{
    itemCollection.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This worked like a charm for me!  The only issue that I see now is when removing and re-adding pushpins, they tend to visually "jump" up a few pixels when they first appear.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're continuing to use the same myItemCollection to hold your current information (if you're binging a source, this should probably be the case), then you shouldn't need to rebind.  Instead, you need to be throwing PropertyChanged events, so that the component will know to update with the source's current contents.  See the [Binding Sources tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx) and [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) from Microsoft for more.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that bindings cannot be used with MaptItemsControl.ItemsSource. The use of binding would make it much more easier to achieve my goal. But dealing with maps in WP8 seems more difficult than with WP7.

Comment: According to the MapItemsControl (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620947.aspx) page, it is for data binding.  It does this as an child class of ItemsControl (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx).

Comment: That's for Bing Maps in Windows Store app. It also worked with Bing Maps in WP7, but not with the MapItemsControl from Windows Phone Toolkit and Nokia Maps in WP8

Comment: Ah, Okay.  I hadn't caught that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DataContext` property. And afaik you don't need to write Clear while using it. Simply try this:

```
var itemCollection = MapExtensions.GetChildren((Map)MyMap).OfType<MapItemsControl>().FirstOrDefault();
itemCollection.DataContext = myItemCollection;
```

Comment: itemCollection does not have DataContext property.

Comment: So what's about to write `itemCollection.ItemsSource = null; itemCollection.ItemsSource = myItemCollection;` ? Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525618/phone-maps-items-collection-must-be-empty-before-using-itemssource

Comment: I get the same error: *Items must be empty before using Items Source*

Answer (score -1):

Urmm.. How about

```
itemCollection.Items = itemCollection.Items.Clear();
```